# [Swiper][Gatsby] Thumbnails slider has mutiple active slides when there are 3 or more slides

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, thumbnails, swiper.js

*Swiper Version: 6.2.0*

*Gatsby version: 2.24.65*

**What you did**

Wanted to add some css to the active thumbnail slide.

[Live Site](https://hungry-kowalevski-954933.netlify.app/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F-1/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0/)

**The Code**

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import SwiperCore, { Thumbs, Zoom } from "swiper"
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react"
import "swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css"
import "lazysizes"
import "lazysizes/plugins/parent-fit/ls.parent-fit"
import Lightbox from "./lightbox"

SwiperCore.use([Thumbs, Zoom])

const Carousel = ({ images }) => {
  const [thumbsSwiper, setThumbsSwiper] = useState(null)
  return (
    <div>
      <Swiper
        thumbs={{ swiper: thumbsSwiper }}
        className=""
        autoHeight={true}
        slidesPerView={1}
      >
        {images.map(slide => (
          <SwiperSlide key={slide.src} zoom={true}>
            <Lightbox image={slide.image.fluid.src}>
              <img
                src={`${slide.image.fluid.base64}`}
                data-srcset={`${slide.image.fluid.srcSet}`}
                data-sizes="auto"
                className="lazyload carousel-image block object-cover w-full"
                alt={`${slide.image.url}`}
              />
            </Lightbox>
          </SwiperSlide>
        ))}
      </Swiper>

      <Swiper onSwiper={setThumbsSwiper} spaceBetween={2} slidesPerView={3}>
        {images.map(slide => (
          <SwiperSlide key={slide.src} className="">
            <img
              src={`${slide.image.fluid.base64}`}
              data-srcset={`${slide.image.fluid.srcSet}`}
              data-sizes="auto"
              className="lazyload object-cover w-full h-20 p-1 mt-1 rounded-lg opacity-75"
              alt={`${slide.image.url}`}
            />
          </SwiperSlide>
        ))}
      </Swiper>
    </div>
  )
}
export default Carousel
```

**CSS**

```
.swiper-slide-thumb-active img { opacity: 1 !important; border-bottom: 3px solid #3ebd93; }
```

**Expected Behavior**

Show active slide correctly. Meaning only the active slide should have green border-bottom

**Actual Behavior**

Well, it's really random. Here's [a GIF showing the behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7PNy.jpg)

Only happens to sliders with more than 2 slides in them.

Comment: Welcome its generaly good practice to paste the actual code instead of linking it, in the eventuallity that the link would become dead thus losing all references to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Instead of styling the image, wrap the image with another element and move your styles to it.

It seems like SwiperJS doesn't seems to use margin, border, and padding in its slide width calculations. I'm not exactly sure how wrapping the image resolves it, but that's what worked for me.